# How can I copy a file from another directory to the current one?

Tags: cp

I have this problem as part of a school assignment:

[image: screenshot]

**NOTE:** In case it's hard to read in the image above, here's the directory tree:

```
$ tree
.
`-- sample_dir1
    `-- sample_dir
        |-- admin
        |-- cambridge
        |   |-- cafeteria
        |   |-- library
        |   `-- security
        |       |-- annex
        |       |-- building
        |       `-- parking
        |-- faculty
        |-- history.exe
        |-- markham
        |   |-- annex
        |   |-- building1
        |   `-- parking
        |-- oxford
        |   |-- outline.doc
        |   |-- programming
        |   |   `-- report.pdf
        |   `-- security
        `-- stenton
            |-- gen_ed
            `-- lib_arts
                |-- english.txt
                `-- match.doc

15 directories, 11 files
```

I tried doing the command:

```
$ cp ../cambridge/security/parking ./parking2
```

...but it isn't working. The question in the image above states that the current directory is `stenton`, and that we need to make a copy of the file named `parking` (from the `security` directory), and to name the new file `parking2`, and place it in the current directory, `stenton`, using relative pathnames.

What am I doing wrong? My `cp` command seems to be correct.

Comment: yes an assignment ^^ stuck on this questions for 1 day now

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html

Comment: @user88022 Sorry for the rough introduction you got here. Not knowing about embedding images is understandable for a new user, but you should explain what you've tried (and how it failed) when asking for help.

Comment: This is ULI101 at Seneca College, which we get year after year.  [All assignments **"MUST consist of the student’s OWN work"**.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/copying-and-relative-home#comment358558_211656)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very elementary question. I would read up on the man pages for this one. But nonetheless, here is your answer:

```
cp <SOURCE> .
```

For example:

I have a file in this directory: `/home/rkah/sample1`
The file is called: `sample`

Say if I wanted to go to my home directory which is: `/home/rkah/` and copy `sample` to `/home/rkah/`, I would run this command:

`cp ~/sample/sample .` The `.` symbol stands for present working directory or the directory im currently in.

Comment: ive tried that cp ../cambridge/security/parking ./parking2 it doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure you typed  the command correctly? What you've typed doesn't seem right.

Comment: I have to rename it to parking2 though.

Comment: I think your misusing the cp command for one. I will provide an example of how to use it in my answer..

Comment: @user88022 that command should work, but your software testing you may be sensitive to `./parking2` since a relative path isn't required to reference the current directory.

Comment: ohh thanks i got it, just had to take out the . but i dont get it, how does it know im copying to the current directory if i dont specify it ?

Comment: @user88022 because not specifying a directory means to use the current directory.  It is implicit.

Comment: @ryekayo he had to copy a file from location1 to location2 with a new name, his first command was right, but he is not in a real shell but a testing software that wants a very specific answer and did not need the `./` to reference the current directory for his destination filename.

Comment: @casey, oh ok I understand. I never used linux commands in testing software before, i was kinda thrown off by that..

Comment: @ryekayo its ok, but realize that his first command you claim is wrong is completely valid for what he wants to do if he were in a real shell.  You misread the question (reading the title and not the actual problem within the image he posted).

Comment: @casey, Understood.

Answer (score 8):

The problem you're running into seems to be with your homework program.

From your comment on the other answer, you tried:

```
cp ../cambridge/security/parking ./parking2
```

This is a perfectly valid command in a normal shell. However the issue is likely that your testing program doesn't want the `./` on the `./parking2`.

When specifying the path to a file (with virtually any program, not just `cp`), if there is no leading `/` on the path, it implicitly becomes `./`. So you should be good if you change your command to:

```
cp ../cambridge/security/parking parking2
```